# RadioSelect widget showing only one word in template in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form like this:

```
account_type_choices = ('1234', '1234567')
choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=account_type_choices)

# In templates shown like this
[li] [radio_button] 2
[li] [radio_button] 2
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`choices` needs to be a series of 2-tuples. Like this:

```
ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES = (('1234', '1234'), ('1234567', '1234567'))
```

(Also note that it's customary to put the name in all caps, since it's a constant.)